# Text for TextView does not get set in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to set some text for a TextView which is hold inside a Fragment. After inflating the layout I retrieve the TextView object using #findViewById(int) and call its #setText(String) afterwards. However, it doesn't work.

This is how my code looks right now:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Inflate the layout for this fragment
  View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quantityfragment, container, false);
  TextView tvpurchasedunits = (TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.tvpurchasedunits);
  tvpurchasedunits.setText("units");
  return V;
}
```

This is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/add_quantityfragment_svquantity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

        <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/ff"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RelativeLayout
                style="@style/fw"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#8BC34A"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/add_quantityfragment_tvpurchasedquantity"
                    style="@style/text_view_body"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Bought"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/add_quantityfragment_etpurchasedquantity"
                    style="@style/edittext"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/add_quantityfragment_tvpurchasedquantity"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/layout_border2"
                    android:digits="0123456789."
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvpurchasedunits"
                    style="@style/text_view_body"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/add_quantityfragment_etpurchasedquantity"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/add_quantityfragment_etexpirydate"
                    style="@style/edittext"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/add_quantityfragment_tvcleardate"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/layout_border2"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:hint="Expiry Date"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/add_quantityfragment_tvcleardate"
                    style="@style/text_view_body"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/clear"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#EEEEEE" />

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/ff"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    style="@style/ff"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#FF5722"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/add_quantityfragment_tvusedquantity"
                        style="@style/text_view_body"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Used"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/add_quantityfragment_etusedquantity"
                        style="@style/edittext"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/layout_border2"
                        android:digits="0123456789."
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/add_quantityfragment_tvusedunits"
                        style="@style/text_view_body"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/add_quantityfragment_etusedquantity"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/add_quantityfragment_tvor"
                    style="@style/text_view_body"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minHeight="40dp"
                    android:text="{Or}" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    style="@style/ff"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#3F51B5"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/add_quantityfragment_tvremainingquantity"
                        style="@style/text_view_body"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Now in Pantry"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/add_quantityfragment_etremainingquantity"
                        style="@style/edittext"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/layout_border2"
                        android:digits="0123456789."
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/add_quantityfragment_tvremainingunits"
                        style="@style/text_view_body"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/add_quantityfragment_etremainingquantity"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The text is not set. I tried to set it in different methods such as #onActivityCreated(), #onStart() and #onResume() but I am just not able to do so.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

But you should `return view;` in your `onCreateView(..)`

```
return V;
```

Like:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quantityfragment, container, false);

    TextView tvpurchasedunits = (TextView).findViewById(R.id.tvpurchasedunits);

    tvpurchasedunits.setText("units");

    return V;
   }
```

Comment: return V is there in the code but i forget to add in the question, Check my edited question

Comment: @user1084968 Check `quantityfragment layout` has `TextView` with id `tvpurchasedunits`

Comment: yes the textview tvpurchasedunits is there in the layout

Comment: @user1084968 Are you sure about this? becoz your code looks like OK.Or check the `position` or `Visibility` of `that TextView`

Comment: textview is visible only, checked that also

Comment: Could you attach your xml-layout?

Comment: @user1084968 Unfortunately your TextView is not visible. It's hide behind some other layout. Your code it's Ok

Comment: when I set text for the textview in the xml code, its visible, tried that also

Comment: @user1084968 Ya that's fine. but you are trying to set it as Run time.Na

Comment: yes i need to set it in run time, but textview is visible

Answer (score 0):

How did you use your fragment? We usually didn't add to a group when the fragment inflated by specifying the container as null.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quantityfragment, null, false);

    TextView tvpurchasedunits = (TextView) V
                .findViewById(R.id.tvpurchasedunits);
    tvpurchasedunits.setText("units");
    return V;
}
```

Comment: This may be a solution to the problem. imho